# Assigning a value to the first empty int

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a simple interface which the user inputs a number into (positive or negative or 0)

I have 20 int variables score1-20

upon pressing a button I then want to cycle through each variable until I find the next empty one and then assign the number the user input. If all variables have values then I will do a calculation.

```
int score1.....score20;


calculateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             //code to convert an input value to an int

                if(score1 == null)
                   score1 = currentScore;

               //else-if statements to go through all 20 scores until one is not null. If you 
                populate score20 then do another calculation to give the final output.

             }
            }
        });
```

I know there is probably a better way to cycle through them using a for loop.

Is there a better way to check if the int is empty rather than changing the data type to an Integer which can be null? I don't want to assign all the ints as 0 as the int could potentially hold a value of 0

Comment: I don't quite understand: If you neither want to use an Object like Integer but also don't want to treat a value like "0" as being an empty value what exactly is your definition of the int being "empty"?

Comment: use an `ArrayList` and add all scores until `size()` returns `20`

Comment: The user is putting a score in, so the score could be for example -5 but it could also be 0 or it could be 10.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an ArrayList and add the user input until the list has a specific length and then you do your calculation

Comment: The list needs to be fluid, so that once all 20 scores are valid, the next time a user inputs a score, score 20 would be replaced by 19, 19 by 18 etc and the new score would be score1. Is this possible using the ArrayList? Also later in the calculation I need to arrange the 20 scores by value and then average the 8 lowest scores.. So not sure this would work.

Comment: you could introduce an counter and add the current value at the counter position (you also could use an array then instead of an array list). if the counter hits 20 you calculate and reset the counter